# Xampp com problema no MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

Meu MySQL não abre, erro:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:26:46  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:26:46  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:26:46  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:26:46  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:26:46  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:26:46  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Editado:

Não adiantou. O problema aqui está sendo o MySQL e não o apache. O erro que está dando no log é este:

```
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-02-13 15:16:11 1200 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Binlog end
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Perdão, com esse título que ninguém ajuda MESMO. Altere o título descreva melhor o erro para não acabar sendo punido por bobagem.

Comment: você usa XAMP ? e também skype?

Comment: Usava skype e xampp mas ja me falaram que buga a port ai feche e msm assim continua dando

Comment: Bem-vindo Augusto, **faça um tour**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para entender como funciona a comunidade e leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking Não vai levar 5 minutos para ler. Obrigado.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o seu problema e se quiser [edit] a sua pergunta é só clicar em [edit].

Comment: Acho que o seu principal problema são estas duas mensagens: `2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1` e `2015-02-13 15:16:11 6140 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace.` - No entanto, não sei como resolver, mas fica aí uma pista para quem souber.

Answer (score 1):

Modifique as portas no `httpd.conf` para parar o conflito entre portas.

Procure por:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

Mude para:

```
ServerName localhost:81
```

Procure por:

```
Listen 80
```

Mude para:

```
Listen 81
```

Após isto reinicie o xamp.

[Encontrei Aqui [XAMP NOT STARTING IN WINDOWS 8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339850/apache-2-4-3-with-xampp-1-8-1-not-starting-in-windows-8)

Comment: po nao adiantou o problema aqui esta sendo o mysql e nao o apache.. o erro que ta dando no log e este...

Comment: executa o setup_xampp.bat

Answer (score 0):

vai em gerenciador de tarefas e finaliza as tarefas de mysql depois starta o mysql no xampp.